# C# Tools: How to rename a lot of tools fast

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Suppose i have 1000 labels, and i want to rename all 1000 of them, is there             any way to speed up the process? or do i need to manually rename all these     labels from the properties tab by repeating the process 1000 times?

```
Ex:
Label1 = lbl1
Label2 = lbl2
Label3 = lbl3
.
.
.
Label1000 = lbl1000
```

Comment: Do a 'Find and replace'? Search for Label, replace with Lbl?

Comment: The first question is: why?
The second question is: why in gods name do you do that?
The answer might be: use a regex to process the file.

Comment: The fact you have 1000 labels is a pretty big red flag to me! Why do you have that? Surely you're better off creating them in code on demand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex in the Find and Replace dialog in Visual Studio.

Find: `Label([0-9]+)`

Replace: `lbl$1`